# How can I stop Nautilus from dereferencing symlinks?

Tags: nautilus, 13.04, symbolic-link

I use symbolic links to tidy my home folder. This works well in the terminal, since the links create the illusion of normal folders:

[image: Symbolic link in GNOME Terminal - Ubuntu 13.04]

In Nautilus, however, the links behave more like [Windows shortcuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut), immediately teleporting me to their target:

[image: Symbolic link in Nautilus - Ubuntu 13.04]

This is particularly troubling when¹ I later want to navigate "up" to the parent folder, as it strands me somewhere outside of the tree I've carefully tidied.

How can I make Nautilus show symbolic links as normal folders, like the terminal does?

### Details

- Nautilus did not dereference symlinks in Ubuntu 12.10:

  [image: Symbolic link in Nautilus and GNOME Terminal - Ubuntu 12.10]
- Maybe this new behavior is just a bug? I'm not sure how to tell. Here's what I know:

  - It's not on the [Nautilus 3.6 Roadmap](https://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Roadmap/3.6).
  - I've skimmed the [recently closed Nautilus bugs](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?chfieldto=2012-09-26&query_format=advanced&chfieldfrom=2012-04-16&bug_status=RESOLVED&product=nautilus) and didn't see anything related.
  - The Nautilus mailing list archive [doesn't mention the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=(inurl:mail.gnome.org%2Farchives%2Fnautilus-list%2F2012+OR+inurl%3Amail.gnome.org%2Farchives%2Fnautilus-list%2F2013)+(symlink+OR+%22symbolic+link%22+OR+symlinks+OR+%22symbolic+links%22)).
  - I received no response from about 120 idlers when posing the question on the GNOME IRC channel.
  - A change was made in Nautilus 3.6 to [resolve symbolic links before launching applications](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?id=65c02e).
- ¹ This is an example. A workaround for this particular scenario does not constitute an answer to my question. Since people seem to be interested in discussing it, though:

  - Using the Back button is not a suitable workaround; it does not always take me to the parent folder.
  - You can navigate up by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.
  - The desired behavior in this example is for "up" to navigate to the parent folder of the symbolic link. The current behavior is to navigate to the parent folder of the target of the symbolic link.

Comment: Nautilus doesn't exhibit this behavior in 12.04. Sounds like a pre-release bug.

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior with 13.04 "beta2" and Nautilus 3.6.3: the back arrow really leads to the previous visited location and not the up one.

Comment: @Victor The Back button works as expected, navigating to the previous location. There doesn't seem to be an Up button (not sure if/when it was removed), but pressing Alt+Up should take you to the parent folder.

Comment: @ændrük I'm really not sure I understand what you're looking for... Alt+Up does take me to the parent folder and Alt+Left to the previous location. Otherwise as far as I know it is not possible to get Nautilus to consider this link as being a normal folder rather than a link. What would be the advantage of it? For other users?

Comment: @Victor _Which_ parent folder does it take you to? The parent of the symlink, or the parent of the symlink's target? In an ideal solution to my question, it would take you to the parent of the symlink.

Comment: alt+up takes me back to where I started @ændrük (so the original directory and not the one where the link is stored).

Comment: @ændrük Alt+Up takes me to the parent folder of the symlink's target. Hopefully my dumb questions will be useful for others to answer you... Good luck!

Comment: IMO, after open a symlink: if you go **Back**, you should see the previous folder (symlink *container*). If you go **Up**, you should see the parent folder of this folder (the symlink target folder).

Comment: @Lucio That's only true if, by coincidence, the previous location happens to also be the parent folder of the symlink. In some (read: my) usage patterns, this condition is frequently not met.

Comment: Do you have to use Nautilus?  There are other good file managers.

Comment: @blujay I'm interested in learning how to better use the default file manager.

Comment: To me, this is a real troubling BUG! I hate this behavior, have lots of symlinks from home partition which is a SSD to my HDD. When this change came unexpectedly, it struck me by surprise. When I click around in my personal home folder, all the time my breadcrumb bar is kind of broken, I cannot get back by going up! PLEASE. Change this back or make this an option I can switch on or off!!

Comment: This bug is still present in 3.8.2; very annoying.

Comment: I find that the `Nemo` (1.8.4) File Manager (default in XFCE) doesn't suffer from this "bug". Another nice side-effect of switching to XFCE. I didn't try, but probably one can install `Nemo` and use it as default. Also see my workaround in `Nautilus` below.

Comment: Upstream bug report: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702301

Comment: Bug report in Launchpad: [Nautilus does not properly navigate symbolic links](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1184720)

Comment: The bug is still in Nautilus `3.10.1` (I am using it from Fedora 20)

Comment: `Thunar` doesn't have this problem. This is a serious bug.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in Nautilus 3.14 (I am using it from Fedora 21)

Answer (score 2):

This one is a workaround, but may not constitute the actual answer you're trying to find:

On nautilus, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, type in the symlink name (e.g. `link` or `./link`), Enter. It will not dereference the symlink this time.

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: this TERRIBLE BUG apparently is now fixed in Nautilus 3.14.2,
>   what follows is a workaround for older versions

I found this workaround:

1. Install `Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool`
2. Run `nautilus-actions`
3. Add an action called "Open Link"
4. In the "Command" Tab -> Path: `/usr/bin/nautilus`, Parameters:
   `--no-default-window %u` (optional) Menu Edit->Preferences->uncheck
   "Create a root 'Nautilus-action' menu, uncheck "Add an 'About' ..."
5. Restart Nautilus (e.g. `xkill`)
6. Right click any symlink folder, a new Nautilus window will open with
   the folder (not the dereferenced folder).

Limitations still: a) Nautilus now has to context menus "Open" and "Open Link" (you have to remember to use the right one), b) a new window opens each time.