# Files (Nautilus?) shows the real location of Symbolic Links

Tags: nautilus, symbolic-link

I some of the "folders" in my home directory are symbolic links to a larger hard drive mounted on `/mnt/data`.

I would like it if when I click on (for example) Music in my home directory, Nautilus showed `~/Music`. Instead it shows `/mnt/data/Music`. Not a bug exactly... but it would be nice if going "up" went back to my home directory instead of to the mount point.

Is there a way to change the behaviour of Nautilus in this regard?

Comment: Okay so interestingly if in Nautilus I click on the shortcut on the left-hand (under "Places"), it works the way I want it to (even several levels deep), but if I open the folder (link) from the home folder itself, it takes me to /mnt/data/folder

Comment: Hey so I just found my question asked [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280431/how-can-i-stop-nautilus-from-dereferencing-symlinks?rq=1). It is articulated much better than I did articulate it. It was asked during the beta it seems so I'll leave this up just in case.

Comment: I found a partial workaround: http://askubuntu.com/a/317605/15943

Comment: Bug fixed in Nautilus 3.14